# How to allow curly braces in command option

Tags: catcodes, xkeyval

I need to store an URL parameter like `` &path=weigth:5|color:orange|enc:okydHa}peAXOHi@jANv@A@kJJmFAiDJuAHmDXcBb@cC`@gC^_DV}CJaCF{APaBVkBdAyEf@qC`@{B\aDSwB `` with later reencoding to `utf8` and passing to a lua script.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\makeatletter
\define@key{testcmd}{arg}[]%
{%
  \gdef\testcmdarg{\detokenize{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand*\testcmd[1][]{\setkeys{testcmd}{#1}}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\testcmd[arg={&path=weight:5|color:orange|enc:}]
%\testcmd[arg=&path=weight:5|color:orange|enc:okydHa}peAXOHi@jANv@A@kJJmFAiDJuAHmDXcBb@cC`@gC^_DV}CJaCF{APaBVkBdAyEf@qC`@{B\aDSwB]
Test: \testcmdarg
% in fact, the option is reencoded to utf8 and passed to a lua script! no output!
\end{document}
```

Most of the problems are solved with `\detokenize`, but the curly braces are still a problem. I guess it has something to do with the catcodes. So how can i change the catcodes and limit the change to the setting of the option?

Or is there another way to store the option as "text"?

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you mean by “reencoded to UTF-8 and passed to a Lua script”, but the issue seems quite clear: you are storing `\detokenize`, rather than executing it.

```
\define@key{testcmd}{arg}[]{%
  \xdef\testcmdarg{\detokenize{#1}}%
}
```

With `\xdef` the replacement text is expanded; in this case `\detokenize` performs its duty and the macro will contain all category code 12 characters.

Comment: It's for the getmap package and the arguments are reencoded to UTF8 and passed to getmapdl.lua. If I change `\gdef` to `\xdef`, I still get `--` instead of `|` in the first example and `! Argument of \testcmd has an extra }.` for the commented second example. So still no braces allowed in options. In `getmap` I've implemented the `pathfile` option so that the lua script can read the problematic path with braces directly from a file. But if there would be a solution that works directly with the `path` option, ...  ;-)

Comment: @Josef You can't have unmatched braces in arguments.